# Transfer files from one VM to another in GCP CE

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am trying to move a file from one VM instance to another using scp method. However I had understood that it is not possible to do the direct transfer from the source instance. e.g
scp db.sql user@instance-src:/home/data/db.sql

I tried using the gcloud scp command but this allows me to do a transfer from local to remote only. This means I need to first download the file from the source to local.

Is there a better way to do this task?

Comment: You can `ssh` into one of of the instances and then execute `scp` to copy files between that instance and another. This requires that you have SSH keypairs setup correctly on each system that you access or copy files to and from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to create public key on the source-vm using the command `ssh-keygen` then you can see the public key using the command `cat .ssh/id_rsa.pub`. Now add the public key of source VM instance to the /home/user-name/.ssh/authorized_keys of destination vm instance. Now, you can transfer the files from the source-vm to the destination-vm as @Johnhanley said.

Alternatively, using the below command you can transfer the file from one VM to another VM using below gcloud command:

```
gcloud compute ssh source-vm --command='scp db.sql user@destination-vm:/home/file-transfer-location --zone=us-central1-a'
```

Comment: I am trying the gcloud compute method to accomplish this. thanks.

Comment: An update to my attempt to ssh into the vm. I tried to use the glcoud compute ssh method to execute the scp command. it failed with connection time out error. So I went ahead with ssh keygen on the source vm, manually paced it on the target VM (auth keys file) and tired the ssh. this is again failing with permission denied(public key) error. is there any GCP specific restriction that could stop me from doing this? This is really frustrating though I am learning something new everyday.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `ssh` maybe a simpler option could be using a GCS bucket as intermediate, temporal, storage in the copy process.

The `gcloud` CLI and the companion `gsutil` tool used for that purpose should be installed in every VM.

Please, be aware that you need to [grant write access](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/using-iam-permissions) to the bucket to the [Compute Engine default service account](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/service-accounts#default_service_account) for this setup work properly.

Comment: Thanks. But I want a simpler option (ssh/scp) than using many different gcp products. If I was dealing with large chunks or  frequent transfers like this, I would have considered this solution.