# Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic). GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssh, centos7, rdp, xfce

I launched a VM with CentOS 7. I configured a GUI and a xrdp with the next .sh file:

```
#!/bin/sh

#Install​ EPEL and nux Desktop repository rpms
rpm -Uvh http://li.nux.ro/download/nux/dextop/el7/x86_64/nux-dextop-release-0-1.el7.nux.noarch.rpm

#Install​ xfce desktop to get the graphical user interface
yum groupinstall -y "Xfce"

#command​ to change the reboot from CLI to GUI
ln -sf /lib/systemd/system/runlevel5.target /etc/systemd/system/default.target

#create xfce clients
echo "xfce4-session" > ~/.Xclients
chmod a+x ~/.Xclients

#Install​ the xrdp
yum -y install xrdp tigervnc-server

#start​ the xrdp service
systemctl start xrdp.service

#enable​ the xrdp service
systemctl enable xrdp.service
```

Everything works fine, i can reach that VM via rdp from my computer, but when i'm in the vm and i try to acces to another vm's in the same project this error appear:

```
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

But it only happens when i try with the vm terminal, if i access from the google ssh client i can access to the other virtual machines without problem.

Another thing: I access to the VM rdp with root user, this could be the problem?

Any ideas?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/65986856/11866104

Comment: You need to create public key on the source-vm using the command ssh-keygen then you can see the public key using the command cat .ssh/id_rsa.pub. Now add the public key of source VM instance to the /home/user-name/.ssh/authorized_keys of destination vm instance.

Comment: You were right! thx. Also worked changing the sshd_config file in the target VM uncommenting the line "#PasswordAuthentication=yes".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Transfer files from one VM to another in GCP CE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65983721/transfer-files-from-one-vm-to-another-in-gcp-ce)

Comment: Not really, but is useful to realize how to send info via ssh